# Echo semicolon in bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to write to a file the following string: `1;2;3;4`. The semicolons create problems.

I have been able to figure out the following ecamotage to do it:

```
variable='1;2;3;4'
echo "${variable//;/\;}" >output.file
```

however if it is executed by crontab for some reason it doesn't produce the output file, it works only if executed manually.

Any alternative to my code?

Comment: Can we see you crontab entry, please? Also, is the crontab entry executed by `bash` or by `/bin/sh` by default, or do you set `$SHELL` in the crontab file?

Comment: Are you *certain* that cron is executing your script in bash? Very often cron is set up to use /bin/sh, which probably doesn't understand bash string replacement expressions even if sh *is* bash (the name used for invocation sets a number of properties of how the shell behaves).

Comment: What problems do you get if you use `echo '1;2;3;4' >output.file`?

Comment: @Kusalananda: 30 14 * * * /home/scripts/test.sh - Michael Kjörling: I am not sure, how can I check? - Alexander Batischev: if you store that string in a variable it prints spaces in place of semicolons.

Comment: So the script is a `bash` script. Sorry, but I can not reproduce this problem. If I do `v='1;2;3;4'` forrowed by `echo "$v" >file`, I get a file containing the string `1;2;3;4`, no matter if I put it in a script or not.

Comment: @Kusalananda: try to run that script with crontab, it still works?

Comment: Still works... Is that the complete script?

Comment: @giovi321: cron jobs run with `/bin/sh`, which doe not have parameter substituion like `${variable//;/\;}`.

Comment: @cuonglm If he runs his job from cron like he say's he does, and if the script `/home/scripts/test.sh` has a `#!`-line invoking `bash` (we don't know this), then it ought to be independent of what shell cron uses, and it should work.

Comment: Well, actually it is a small portion of a larger script. I added #!/bin/sh to the first line of the script and it produces the output file!

Comment: did you mean “escamotage”?

Comment: @richard: yes!! how did you guess?

Comment: I looked it up on google and it said “did you mean ‘escamotage’?”. I have never heard of it before. I always use “prestatdigitation”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, if you want to replace `;` with `\;`, you need to escape the `\`. Remember that `\` is a special character, it is used to escape things (which is, presumably, precisely why you want to add it before the `;`). In order to use it literally, in a substitution, you need to escape it too:

```
$ variable='1;2;3;4'
$ echo "${variable//;/\;}"  ## fails
1;2;3;4
$ echo "${variable//;/\\;}" ## works
1\;2\;3\;4
```

The next issue is that, as Cuonglm pointed out, cron runs everything with `/bin/sh`. Depending on your system, that might be bash running in sh-compatibility mode, or another minimal shell (`dash` on Debian-based systems) or even the venerable bourne shell itself. It is, therefore, quite likely that the `${var//foo/bar}` construct won't work. For example, in `dash`:

```
$ variable='1;2;3;4'
$ echo "${variable//;/\\;}"
dash: 2: Bad substitution
```

However, if all you want is to print a string saved in a variable into a file, this should always work:

```
variable='1;2;3;4'
printf '%s\n' "$variable" > file
```